# Can someone tell me can i use angular 6+ with meteor 1.7?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

angular meteor documentation is showing support for angular version 4.4. Is it depricated.

Answer (score 2):

It works perfectly fine. I’m currently using the release candidate for meteor 1.8, angular 6.1 and the angular meteor driver 3.2 (I think)

All play nicely together. Look at the angular meteor repo and there are example apps. You can use the meteor command line version is you are used to meteor. I cannot comment on using it without the meteor command line as I do not use it this way.